# Visual Studio: create multiple projects under same solution?

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, solution

I would create a Visual Studio C solution, with this kind of structure under a parent directory:

```
Parent/
|
|- SolutionName.sln
|
|- Project1/
|     |
|     |-src/
|        |
|        |- main1.c
|
|- Project2/
     |
     |-src/
        |
        |- main2.c
```

How to do this please?

Already tried multiple things, like creating a solution then Add Project etc, but this generally ends up with the `.sln` in one of the subdirectories; which doesn't reflects the solution structure - all projects are under one big `.sln` umbrella.

There are already on SO a dozen questions around "multiple projects", but no one had answered this simple question.

Answer (score 2):

When you create your first project and solution, the solution gets the name of the first project. Any projects added later are stored under that name.

```
MyFirstProject
   +---------------MyFirstProject
   +---------------MySecondProject
...
```

The parent dir, MyFirstProject contains the .sln file, the subdirs contain the project files.

I would suggest you follow the general setup that Visual Studio uses instead of creating your own custom one for convenience.

Comment: Ok, this is at least a workaround +1 . Problem is that one of the projects would have a privilegied position amongst others. I managed creating a dummy 'project', same name as solution, and then adding other projects....

Comment: @yO_ yes that would do it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably figured out in the past 5 years, but here is the answer:

To have one big `.sln` umbrella, you need to make sure the "*Place solution and project in the same directory*" checkbox is unchecked:

[image]

Otherwise you end up with this:

```
repos
|- Project1/
|    |- Project1.sln
|    |-src/
|       |- main1.c
|- Project2/
     |-src/
        |- main2.c
```

As you see, when the checkbox is checked, you are not able to change the solution name:

[image]

This relates with your "creating a dummy project, then delete it" issue. When the checkbox is unchecked, just change the *Solution Name*:

[image]